# Idiomatic way to write Clojure code for repeatedly reading lines from the console?

Tags: command-line, clojure, functional-programming, console-input

Recently I was writing a little CLI script which needed to repeatedly read dates from the console (the number of dates to read was calculated and could be different each time). Sample Ruby code to give you the idea:

```rb
dates = x.times.collect { print "Enter date: "; Date.parse(gets.chomp) }
```

Just for the heck of it, I wrote the script in Clojure, and wound up using some rather ugly code with `swap!` and `loop...recur`. I'm wondering what the cleanest way to achieve the desired effect in Clojure would be. (Clojure does have `dotimes`, but it doesn't retain the values returned from evaluating the body... as might be expected from a language which emphasizes pure functional programming.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your goal is to end up with a sequence of exactly `x` dates entered by user then:

```
(for [line (repeatedly x read-line)] (DateFormat/parse line))
```

or using `map`:

```
(map DateFormat/parse (repeatedly x read-line))
```

Beware of lazy sequences in Clojure: user will be asked to enter more dates as they are needed. If your goal is for user to enter all dates at once (say at startup) then use `doall`:

```
(map DateFormat/parse (doall (repeatedly x read-line)))
```

This will *read* all dates at once, but will parse them lazily still, so date format validation could fail much later in your program. You can move `doall` one level up to parse promptly as well:

```
(doall (map DateFormat/parse (repeatedly x read-line)))
```

And you can use a helper function to read line with prompt:

```
(defn read-line-with-prompt [prompt]
  (print prompt)
  (read-line))
```

Then replace `read-line` with either:

```
#(read-line-with-prompt "Enter date: ")
```

or

```
(partial read-line-with-prompt "Enter date: ")
```

Comment: Great answer... thanks for providing so many options. I think I will define a `read-date` helper function and simply use `(repeatedly x read-date)`. I think that the subsequent processing will force evaluation before I do anything else with the console, so `doall` will *probably* be unnecessary, but it's great to have that in my toolkit and I'm sure I'll find chances to use it later.

Answer (score 10):

read-line returns nil when the end of file is reached. On the console that is when you press CTRL-d *(CTRL-z on Windows)*.

You could use this code to take advantage of this:

```
(doseq [line (repeatedly read-line) :while line]
    (do-something-with line))
```

If you must read a fixed number of lines you can use:

```
(repeatedly n read-line)
```

Comment: Very interesting use of `:while` in `doseq`, I've never seen it before. Cool!

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
(defn read-dates [n] 
     (doall  (for [_ (range n)] (java.util.Date/parse (read-line)))))

(def my-dates (read-dates 5)) ;Read 5 dates from console
```