# how can i get input line by line in clojure?

Tags: clojure

say I want to have user input a matrix row by row. 
So I first ask for the size of the matrix, 
then I would like to ask for user input rows with prompt like "row 1" "row 2" etc.

The most trivial thing to do seems like to have a mutable vector and use somethinkg like doseq to mutate it.

But I'm curious if there are any more clojure way to do it. 
My initial thought was to use  `for` or `map`. But it is lazy so cannot print out the prompt.
so something like `(map (fn [i] (do (printf "row %d \n" i) (read-line))) (range size))` will include prompt in the result list as well.

Then I thought I could use a macro to just produce something like

```
[((println "row i") (read-line)) 
 ((println "row i") (read-line)) 
 ((println "row i") (read-line)) ...]
```

Are there anyway I can do this without macro or mutable variable? 
Which way is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does what you ask for, provided I understand your question properly:

```
(loop [i   (read-line)
       ret []]
  (println "row" i)
  (if (some-condition)
    ret
    (recur (read-line) (conj ret i))))
```

For example, having the condition as `(= i "x")`:

```
user=> (loop [i (read-line) ret []] (println "row" i) (if (= i "x") ret (recur (read-line) (conj ret i))))
SOME
row SOME
some
row some
XXXX
row XXXX
my my my
row my my my
1
row 1
2
row 2
3
row 3
4
row 4
5
row 5
x
row x
["SOME" "some" "XXXX" "my my my" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"]
user=>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484113/idiomatic-way-to-write-clojure-code-for-repeatedly-reading-lines-from-the-consol) for information around idiomatic ways to read multiple lines from the console.